# Default currency symbol

Tags: apex, visualforce, currency, locale

I'm looking for a way to get the **Default currency symbol** (in a **none-multi-currency** org) of the salesforce org locale (to have it displayed on a visualforce page in a field that can't be `<apex:inputField>` or `<apex:outputField>`) preferably query-able from apex (via the database, a describe or whatever) and then again the actual symbol, meaning € for Euro, $ for dollar, and so on...

There must surely be some sort of mapping hidden in the code somewhere salesforce does this via the input/outputfields if bound to an sobject of type currency

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

We ended up fixing it this way, this hasn't been tested on a multicurrency org but this works on a singlecurrency org.

```
    public static String getCurrencyIsoCode(SObject someObject){
        String currencyIso = UserInfo.isMultiCurrencyOrganization() ? (String) someObject.get('CurrencyIsoCode') : UserInfo.getDefaultCurrency();
        return currencyIso;
    }

    public static String getCurrencySymbol(SObject someObject) {
        return getCurrencySymbolFromIso(getCurrencyIsoCode(someObject));
    }

    public static String getCurrencySymbolFromIso(String Iso) {
         String currencySymbol = 
           ('USD' == Iso ? '$' : 
           ('CAD' == Iso ? '$' : 
           ('EUR' == Iso ? '€' : 
           ('GBP' == Iso ? '£' : 
           ('JPY' == Iso ? '¥' : 
           ('KRW' == Iso ? '₩' : 
           ('CNY' == Iso ? '元' : 
           Iso)))))));
           return currencySymbol;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

`SELECT DefaultLocaleSidKey FROM Organization`

returns "de_DE_EURO" or "en_GB" for me, so still some way towards getting "EUR" out of it.

No idea if there's better way but if not -> you could play with string.split() or use Eclipse to learn all picklist values and write some mapping code?

---

To get the €,$ etc. use tricks from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3888991/currency-code-to-currency-symbol-mapping

VF:

```
<apex:outputText value="{0, number, ¤ #}">
    <apex:param value="{!Opportunity.Amount}" /><!-- gives me "$ 50000" -->
</apex:outputText>
```

In Apex - tricky. You could experiment with String.format() but it expects an array of strings so that's where you'd lose the "currency-ness" of your number.

Comment: I was actually hoping of getting the € somehow :)

Comment: Tricks from Java code do not help in Salesforce. If we tried to use Java solution like "Currency.getInstance('EUR').getSymbol()" it would say: "Variable does not exist: Currency".

Comment: @Patlatus that's true, I've meant here the `¤` symbol that (when used in Visualforce) does produce something. Check http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currency_sign_(typography) too.

Comment: Yes, @eyescream, it DOES produce something.. It seems though that the ¤ symbol only shows a '$' in my tests..

I tried changing my user currency to GBP, and the Account record's currency also [I'm playing with the AnnualRevenue field on Account], and I haven't got a £ yet..

Answer (score 0):

We could use connectApi to get currency details.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_connectapi_output_features.htm

We can use default​Currency​IsoCode in ConnectApi.Features to get iso code.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_connectapi_output_usersettings.htm

We can use currencySymbol in ConnectApi.UserSettings to get currency symbol.

```
ConnectApi.OrganizationSettings  orgSettings = ConnectApi.Organization.getSettings();
system.debug(orgSettings.UserSettings.currencySymbol);
system.debug(orgSettings.features.defaultCurrencyIsoCode);
```

This solution will only work in Single currency org. For multiCurrency org use userinfo.CurrencyIsoCode().